# for loop to iterate 2 arrays of different length and if the bigger one includes the property of the other extract the property (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Please help. I have an exercize in javascript that gives two arrays of countries like the following:

```
const arr1 =[ "GR",  "DE","AF","FR"];
const arr2 =[{ "code": "AF", "code3": "AFG", "name": "Afghanistan"},
            { "code": "GQ", "code3": "GNQ", "name": "Equatorial Guinea" }, 
            { "code": "FI", "code3": "FIN", "name": "Finland" },
            { "code": "FR", "code3": "FRA", "name": "France" },
            { "code": "GF", "code3": "GUF", "name": "French Guiana" },
            { "code": "PF", "code3": "PYF", "name": "French Polynesia" },
            { "code": "GA", "code3": "GAB", "name": "Gabon", },
            { "code": "GM", "code3": "GMB", "name": "Gambia (the)"  },
            { "code": "GE", "code3": "GEO", "name": "Georgia"  },
            { "code": "GH", "code3": "GHA", "name": "Ghana", },]

let arr3=[];
```

I want to iterate these two arrays with javascript for-loop and if arr1 property is included in arr2 code then extract arr2 full object in arr3

I have this code:

```
    for(i=0;i<arr1.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j<arr2.length; j++){
        if (arr2[j].code.includes(arr1[i]));{
              
             //do something to export the object in question  
       
}
    }}
```

Expected Output:

```
arr3 = [{ "code": "AF", "code3": "AFG", "name": "Afghanistan"},
        { "code": "FR", "code3": "FRA", "name": "France" }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to iterate through the `arr` looking for the elements with the `code` in `arr1`

```js
const arr1 = ["GR", "DE", "AF", "FR"];
const arr = [{"code":"AF","code3":"AFG","name":"Afghanistan"},{"code":"GQ","code3":"GNQ","name":"Equatorial Guinea"},{"code":"FI","code3":"FIN","name":"Finland"},{"code":"FR","code3":"FRA","name":"France"},{"code":"GF","code3":"GUF","name":"French Guiana"},{"code":"PF","code3":"PYF","name":"French Polynesia"},{"code":"GA","code3":"GAB","name":"Gabon"},{"code":"GM","code3":"GMB","name":"Gambia (the)"},{"code":"GE","code3":"GEO","name":"Georgia"},{"code":"GH","code3":"GHA","name":"Ghana"}];
let arr3 = arr.filter(item => arr1.includes(item.code));
console.log(arr3);
```

Using a `for` loop,

```js
const arr1 = ["GR", "DE", "AF", "FR"];
const arr = [{"code":"AF","code3":"AFG","name":"Afghanistan"},{"code":"GQ","code3":"GNQ","name":"Equatorial Guinea"},{"code":"FI","code3":"FIN","name":"Finland"},{"code":"FR","code3":"FRA","name":"France"},{"code":"GF","code3":"GUF","name":"French Guiana"},{"code":"PF","code3":"PYF","name":"French Polynesia"},{"code":"GA","code3":"GAB","name":"Gabon"},{"code":"GM","code3":"GMB","name":"Gambia (the)"},{"code":"GE","code3":"GEO","name":"Georgia"},{"code":"GH","code3":"GHA","name":"Ghana"}];
let arr3 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const item = arr[i];
  if (arr1.includes(item.code)) arr3.push(item);
}

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: how to accept it? because i'm new to the site. Also can i do this with for loop?