# How to filter array of object with array of string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

suppose I have an array of object arr1
`arr1 = [{name: "name1",id: 1},{name: "name2",id: 1},{name: "name3",id: 4},{name: "name3",id: 3},{name: "name1",id: 5}]`

I want to filter it with array `arr2 =["name1","name3"]`

I tried using **filter** then **.some**. But not getting correct data.

required `arr3 = [{name: "name1",id: 1},{name: "name3",id: 4},{name: "name3",id: 3},{name: "name1",id: 5}]`

Comment: Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020872/for-loop-to-iterate-2-arrays-of-different-length-and-if-the-bigger-one-includes/67020937#67020937

Comment: arr1.filter(e => arr2.indexOf(e.name) != -1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const res = arr1.filter(item => arr2.includes(item.name));
```

Comment: I think it must be `.includes(item.name)`

Answer (score 0):

First I would create a `Set` out of `arr2`.

Then I would use the `filter` method to select only the elements that are present in the set.

```js
arr1 = [
  { name: 'name1', id: 1 },
  { name: 'name2', id: 1 },
  { name: 'name3', id: 4 },
  { name: 'name3', id: 3 },
  { name: 'name1', id: 5 },
];

arr2 = ['name1', 'name3'];

arr3 = [
  { name: 'name1', id: 1 },
  { name: 'name3', id: 4 },
  { name: 'name3', id: 3 },
  { name: 'name1', id: 5 },
];

const s = new Set(arr2);

console.log(arr1.filter(a => s.has(a.name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for better performance.

```js
const arr1 = [{name: "name1",id: 1},{name: "name2",id: 1},{name: "name3",id: 4},{name: "name3",id: 3},{name: "name1",id: 5}];
let set = new Set(["name1","name3"]);
let res = arr1.filter(({name})=>set.has(name));
console.log(res);
```